# Display User with "most completed" in Views using Rails counter_cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building my first RoR application and it involves Assignments with Tasks. The user has the ability to Create Assignments, add Tasks to those assignments, and also mark assignments complete. I have an "Accomplishments" page that show cases a featured User with "most completed" assignments (User that has more than 5 assignments completed). Where my problem lies is that the User doesn't change as the assignments completed count does. Currently I only have 2 users. User1 has completed 8 assignments, User2 has completed 7 assignments. User2 is being displayed as the "Featured User with most completed assignments".

My code is as follows:
Assignments Controller

```
class AssignmentsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
    before_action :set_assignment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, 
   :destroy]

  #GET/ASSIGNMENTS
  def index
    user = User.find params[:user_id]
    @incomplete_assignments = user.assignments.incomplete
    @complete_assignments = user.assignments.complete
  end#index

  def new
    @assignment = current_user.assignments.build
    @assignment.tasks.build
  end#new

  #POST
  def create
    @assignment = current_user.assignments.build(assignment_params)
     if @assignment.save
       redirect_to [current_user, @assignment], notice: "Assignment was created successfully!"
     else
       render :new
     end
   end #create

   def show
      #@user = current_user.assignments
      @task = Task.new
    end#show

#PATCH
   def edit
   end

  def update
    @assignment.update(assignment_params)

    redirect_to [current_user, @assignment], notice: "Assignment updated successfully!"
  end#update


 #DELETE
  def destroy
    @assignment.destroy

    redirect_to [current_user, @assignment], notice: "Assignment was deleted successfully!"
  end #destroy

  def completed
     Assignment.where(id: params[:assignment_ids]).update_all(status: true)

     redirect_to user_assignments_path(current_user.id)
  end#completed

   private
#STRONG PARAMS
   def set_assignment
     @assignment = Assignment.find(params[:id])
   end

   def assignment_params
     params.require(:assignment).permit(:name, :due_date, task_attributes: [:name])
   end

end#class
```

Users Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @assignment = Assignment.new

    redirect_to user_path(@user)
  end

  def show_completed
    @users = User.all
  end

end
```

My view with Accomplishments

```
<h3> Status of who has done what</h3>
  <br>
    <% for user in @users %>
      <%= user.email %> has completed <%= user.assignments.count %> assignments. <br>
    <% end %>

<% if user.assignments.complete.count > 5 %>
<h1> **Featured User** </h1>
  <h2><%= user.email %> has completed the most assignments!</h2>
    <% else %>
     <p> Not enough completed Assignments to be featured!</p>
  <% end %>

  <%= link_to 'Back to your asssignments', user_assignments_path(current_user, @assignment) %>
```

This may be a matter of a misunderstanding on how to properly use .count in a method, or something as simple as that in my View where I say display the user with assignments greater than 5 my application is doing just that.

Comment: It looks like you close the `for` loop with `@users`, where is that second `user` variable coming from?  The one in the line `<% if user.assignments.complete.count > 5 %>`, what user is populating that variable?  Since there is no loop going on is it possible it is just selecting the first one, it does not look like there is any loop there?

Comment: @RockwellRice, you know, honestly, I did not even notice that. Your guess is as good as mine when it comes to where that variable is coming from or how it's working. I never got an error when you run the application so I assumed, all was well. When I do remove that <% end %>  that closes the initial loop, it shows both Users as a featured User and I was trying to come up with a way to only show the one with the highest count. I don't think it will be as simple as I had hoped it would be.